# How to avoid System.OutOfMemoryException in c# when building a non recombining trinomial tree

Tags: c#, list, memory-management, out-of-memory

I have "successfully" implemented a non recombining trinomial tree to price certain fixed-income derivatives. (Something like shown in the picture below - but with three branches that don't reconnect) [image: this picture]

Unfortunately it turned out that the number of nodes I can use was severely limited by the available memory. If I build a tree with 20 time-steps this results in 3^19 nodes (so 1,1 Billion nodes)

The nodes of each time step are saved in `List<Node>` and these arrays are stored in a `Dictionary<double,List<Node>>`

Each node is instantiated via `new Node(...)`. I also instantiate each of the lists and the dictionary via `new Class()`  Perhaps this is the source of my error.

Also `System.OutOfMemoryException` isn't thrown because of the Dictionary/List-Object being to large (as is often the case) but because I seem to have too many Nodes - after a while `new Node(...)` can't allocate any further memory. Eventually the 2GB max List-Capacity will also kick in I think - seeing as how List grows exponentially larger with each time step.

Perhaps my data-structure is too wasteful or not really suited for the task at hand.

A possible solution could be to save the tree to a text-file thus avoiding the memory-problem completely. This however would necessitate a HUGE workaround.

**Edit:**
To add some more background. I need the tree to price path dependant products. This means that unfortunately I will have to access all the nodes. What is more after the tree has been build I start from the leaves and go backwards in time to determine the price. I also already only generate the nodes I need.

**Edit2:**
I have given the topic some though and also considered the various responses. Could it be that I just need to serialize the respective tree levels to the hard-drive. So basically - I create one time-step (`List<Node>`) write it to Disk etc. Later on when I start from the leaves - I will just have to load it in reverse oder.

Comment: Is this running on a x64?

Comment: the system-screen of my PC at work says 64 bit

Comment: @AndreyLujankin And are you compiling your program as a 64 bit application to leverage this, or are you compiling it as a 32 bit application?

Comment: I would avoid using objects if you want to be more memory effective, almost anything can be stored to simple array, but it is not a solution just moving the cap a little higher. Also note a list can take up to twice memory of its used capacity.

Comment: I wonder if allowing for very large objects would be a workaround? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh285054(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: @Andrew - I have already looked into this approach. I don't think it would apply in my case seeing as to how I just have a lot of small objects. Later on if `List<Node>` should get out of hand I will come back to it.

Comment: @AndreyLujankin Yes your `Lists` aren't big... but the `dictionary` has a billion references... So it may betting large.

Comment: @wondra I agree - but the structure with the nodes seemed more tangible to me. The node-objects could in my case be substitute by a 5-entry array. Also this would lead to significantly less transperent code.

Comment: @Andrew - Okey I will give it a shot.

Comment: Sadly, less transparent code is the price for efficiency. The lower you go in programing comfort the more performance you gain (and less safety).

Comment: @wondra - how much less memory does an array cost compared to an object ? (let's say the object has a constructor, a getter and a setter)

Comment: To be precise, you would have to test it, but in theory you can store all data only by value + one pointer to them. Assuming you have the values as floats, 32bit = 4 bytes / node. Its the least memory you could ever achieve. This brings me to one thing - you cant have 1,2 billion nodes in 2GB ram even if it were only shorts.

Comment: @wondra - problem: in a tree the objects must have some type of relationship - I have to know which nodes are connected. Thus I would need to build some type of scaffolding to enable this. Also I will end up with a huge dictionary and huge Lists all the same. I will think some more on it.

Comment: How are you accessing this data once you've created the tree? Do you normally have to traverse the tree?  Do you need all of the nodes of depth n?  Do you need to get the children of node x?  If you traverse the tree do you do so from root or the leaves?

Comment: No. Acutally you dont need any connection between nodes if you can calculate width of every level of tree. Imagine you flatten the tree, in one row - level by level. You know EXACTLY where the assosiated nodes are. Ignore this message if your tree nodes can have variable number of children. I admit, i didnt look up your tree theory, but from image it looks pretty stright-forward, each node got 2 children(of which are some shared ofc).

Comment: Sorry, three children.. can you link image how exactly does the tree look like?

Comment: @NickBray - I build the tree from the first node. After one has build the tree one goes backward - starting from the leaves. Unfortunately I need to consider all the nodes for path-dependant products. E.g. American Options etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What we have here is a classic problem of doing an enormous amount of processing up front... and then storing EVERYTHING into memory to be processed at a later time.

While simple, given harsh enough conditions (like having a billion entries), it will eat up all the memory.

Now, the OP didn't really specify what the intention of the tree was or how it was going to be used... but I would propose that instead of building it all at once... build it as you need it.

**Lazy Evaluation with `yield`**

Instead of doing everything all at once and having to store it... it might be ideal to do it ONLY when you actually require it.  Check out this [post](http://artisansoftware.blogspot.com/2014/01/synopsis-creating-large-collection-by.html) for more info and examples of using `yield`.

This won't work great though if you need to traverese the tree a bunch of times... but it might still allow you to have deeper depth than you currently do.

Answer (score 3):

You basically have two choices. evaluate only the branches you care about (Andrew's yield) and don't store results *or* build up your tree and save it to disk and implement a custom collection interface on top of it that accesses the right part of the disk.  In this case you are still going to keep a minimal amount of data in your process memory and rely on the OS to do proper disk caching to make access fast.  If you start working with large data sets the second option is a good tool to have in your tool belt, so you should probably write this with reuse in mind.

Comment: Note, in later versions of .NET there are some nice [caching classes built in](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.caching.memorycache%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). So you can persist the entire object to disk but let as much as possible stay cached in memory and when you have a cache miss then you go to the disk to re-read the data.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain those caching clases you mentioned look very intersting. I have never worked with sth. like that befor :)

Comment: another thought - as far as I know cach happens to be in the CPU and not the disk or am I confusing something ?

Comment: @AndreyLujankin Caching is a generic strategy and can happen lots of places. WRT to disk caching, Windows will try to keep frequently used files in RAM so that when you do a read its just copying memory instead of reading bytes off the disk. I believe that the caching objects Scott mentioned can be used to try to keep a manageable set of objects with the idea that you are going to use something like Disk or DB to hold the full collection.

Comment: @Yaur I understand his suggestion. And it actually makes sense. At any given time I onle need the tree nodes for a certain time t_n. Thus the rest of the tree could be stored somewhere and accessed when needed. Unfortunately I don't have the experience to judge what could be the best approach to achieve that. Serialization or the Caching Classes ? Also how would I implement the latter.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think Serializing to disk will help much. One, when you attempt to deserialize the list you will still run out of memory (as, to the best of my knowledge, there is no way to partially deserialize an object).

Have you considered changing your data structure into a relational database model and storing it in a SQLEXPRESS database?

This would give you the added benefit of performing queries with indexes instead of your custom tree traversal logic.

Comment: Yes I have considered it. Unfortunately I do not know whether data-base-usage will work if I want to make the code avaliable as an Excel-Xll (via Excel-DNA)