# Fastet / most efficient way to work with very large Lists (in c#)

Tags: c#, list, stream, containers, large-data

This question is related to the discussion [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21024107/how-to-avoid-system-outofmemoryexception-in-c-sharp-when-building-a-non-recombin) but can also be treated stand alone.
Also I think it would be nice to have the relevant results in one separate thread. I couldn't find anything on the web that was dealing with the topic comprehensively.

Let's say we need to work with a very very large `List<double>` of Data (e.g. 2 Billion entries).

Having a large list loaded into the memory leads to either a  `"System.OutOfMemoryException"`
or if one uses `<gcAllowVeryLargeObjects  enabled="true|false" />` eventually just eats up the entire memory.

**First: How to minimize the size of the container:**

- would an Array of 2 Billion doubles be less expensive ?
- use decimals instead of doubles ?
- is there a data-tye even lesse expensive than  decimal in C# (-100
  to 100 in 0.00001 steps would do the job for me)

**Second: Saving the data to disc and reading it**

- What would be the fastet way to save the List to the disk and read it again?

Here I think the size of the file could be a problem. A txt-file containing 2 Billion entries will be huge - opening it could turn out to take years. (Perhaps some type of stream between the programm and the txt - file would do the job ?) - some sample code would be much appreciated :)

**Third: Iteration**

- if the List is in memory I think using [yield](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9k7k7cf0.aspx) would make sense.
- if the List is saved to the disk the speed of iteration is mostly limited by the speed at
  which we can read it from the disc.

Comment: 2 billion data points is a lot of data regardless of what the data points are. It will take a significant chunk of memory, significant time to iterate over, and significant time to read from/write to disk or elsewhere. That is not to say it can't be optimized (it almost certainly can, and at this scale micro optimizations become useful), but don't expect miracles.

Comment: @delnan I don't expect any miracles. I was just researching the topic online for a couple of days and couldn't find a comprehensive guide to work with. Thus I thought stackOverflow would be a good place to place it. Linking to the relevant SO-posts would do the job in most cases.

Comment: You could try to have a list of lists. What i mean by that is split up the enormous list into a bunch of smaller lists. Use a dictionary to hold these lists. Then when loading you only have to check the dictionary then iterate over the smaller list to get what you want. This may or may not be feasible for what you are doing.

Comment: @deathismyfriend wouldn't a huge dictionary eat up even more space than `List<double>` ?

Comment: [Lazy lists in C#](http://porg.es/blog/lazy-lists-in-c)

Comment: @Audrey It wouldn't be a huge dictionary only a dictionary to hold a bunch of lists to make lookup faster.

Comment: An interesting topic. I believe C# with SQL is the only real solution here. A list in Memory is just too slow! Our Data and Data Access times are quickly bottle necking in todays world and this will only get worse.